# Rank of a simple matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

While solving an exercise I arrived to this simple matrix and I want to get its rank
It is
$$\begin{pmatrix}2\cos 2t\\
\cos t
\end{pmatrix}$$

It is written in the solution that the rank is 1, they took 2 cases if $\cos t=0$ which is easy and the other case when $\cos t \ne 0$, and this second case is the one I didn't understand.

Help please by showing steps and by giving the precise definition of a rank, it is the number of nonzero rows in a matrix?

Comment: The rank cannot be larger than $1$ because the matrix has only one column. The rank cannot be $0$ because $\cos 2t$ and $\cos t$ are never simultaneously $0.$ See lso https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)

Comment: The rank of an $m\times n$ matrix can never be larger than $\min\{m,n\}$ because the rank is the number of linearly independent rows (or linearly independent columns, these are always the same). So in this case the rank must be either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: It is $t$ fixed? Or you are using that coef. as functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\cos(t)=0$ then $t=\pi  n-\frac{\pi }{2}$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ so $2\cos(2t)=2\cos\left(2\left(\pi  n-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\right)=2\cos\left(-\pi\right)=-2$ and your matrix is $\left(-2,0\right)$.

If $\cos(t)\neq0$ then your matrix is not $(0,0)$

The rank is the dimension of the space spanned by the columns. Since your matrix has only a single column, it has rank $0$ if it is the $0$ matrix (i.e. it spans a zero dimensional space because it can only generate a single point, the origin) and $1$ otherwise since it generates a line, a one-dimensional object.

Since we've shown the matrix is never the $0$ matrix, it has rank $1$.